# im using firebase for the laravel an error is displayed saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: laravel, firebase-realtime-database

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Comment: Where is this included? You can't use `import` without tranpsiling it through something like webpack.

Comment: how to import these webpack? im really confused

Comment: Make a file called `app.js` and put your code in it. Then read [the documentation on Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) and voila